# CKEditor 4 How to disable the image upload popup?

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor4.x, fckeditor

I am using CKEditor 4.13 version. When i copy paste or drag and drop an image on the ckeditor a dialog opens like this [click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mL9M4.png) . How to disable this popup?

I am very new to this. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Download and Install ckfinder and configure with your ckeditor.